# How do I create and setup a Vue 3 typescript Plugin?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to create a new Plugin in Vue 3 using Typescript.

My Code generally is:

```
//somePlugin
import { App, Plugin } from "vue";

const somePlugin: Plugin = {
  install: async (app: App, options: {...}): Promise<void> => {
    ....
  }
}
export { somePlugin };
//----------------------------------------------------------
//main.ts
import { somePlugin } from "@/plugins/somePlugin";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(somePlugin);
```

I however get the following Error:

```
Cannot find module '@/plugins/somePlugin' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I a bit new to Typescript to be honest, but I thought that "somePlugin" is defined by the Vue internal "Plugin" and therefore is completely typed and declared.

Following the answers of similar Problems I guessed I should create a "somePlugin.d.ts",
but I don't really know what I should declare here but I tried this:

```
declare module "somePlugin";
```

But that didn't work. So I either need a working example of a Vue 3 Typescript Plugin or a Tip on how to declare that Plugin so it works.

I also would like to refrein of using ts-ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I embarrassingly have to admit, that it was caused by a wrong link.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a problem in your tsconfig.json (Typescript configuration) file. I created a new vue 3 project and it works for me. Here is the current tsconfig.json file of a new project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```